# NestJs throttling behind Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, nestjs, reverse-proxy, throttling

I'm trying to configure Rate limits with Nestjs and Throttle. It all works fine until I put the app behind Nginx reverse-proxy.

Then the only Ip I get from clients is ::1 or ::127.0.0.1.

The [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting) says that:

> If your application runs behind a proxy server, check the specific HTTP adapter options ([express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) and fastify) for the trust proxy option and enable it.

so following the express link I put in main.ts:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback') // specify a single subnet
```

And then I get error:

> Property „set” does not exist in type „INestApplication”.ts(2339)

any idea how to solve this issuie?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`set` is available on the express instance, and is accessible via `NestExpressApplication`. You can tell Typescript your `app` is a `NestExpressApplication` via the `NestFactory.create` generic: `const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule)`